# How can I toggle the display of an array that is located within each object of another array that comes from an API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, toggle, display

For example:
I'm displaying multiple `Student` objects to the website that's coming from an API. Each `Student` object contains an array of their test `Grades` along with other student information. Now, I want to display each `Student`'s information onto the screen but instead of displaying the student's `Grades`, I want each `Student` to have a `"+"` `Button` which will be to toggle the display of the student's `Grades`.

I'm using the useState hook from React. My problem is that when I click the `"+"` `Button`, it toggles ALL student's grades on/off. What I want is to toggle the `Grades` of only the student whose button I clicked.

Here's my code:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styles from "./Home.module.css";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const Home = () => {

  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const [filteredStudents, setFilteredStudents] = useState([]);
  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(true);

  const fetchStudents = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students`);
    setStudents(response.data.students);
    setFilteredStudents(response.data.students);
    console.log(response.data.students);

  }

  const findAverageGrade = arr => {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sum += parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
    return sum / arr.length;
  }

  const searchStudentName = async (searchName) => { 
    const searchNameFiltered = searchName.toLowerCase();
    console.log(searchNameFiltered);
    
    if (searchNameFiltered === "") {
      fetchStudents();
      return;
    }

    var newArray = await students.filter((student) => {
      return student.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchNameFiltered)
      || student.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchNameFiltered);
    })

    await setFilteredStudents(newArray);
  }

  const toggleGrades = () => {
    console.log("toggle");
    
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStudents();

  }, [])
  

  return(
    <>
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search by name" onChange={(event) => searchStudentName(event.target.value) }/>
        {filteredStudents.map((student) => (
          <div key={student.email} className={styles.studentItem}>
            <img className={styles.studentImage} src={student.pic} />
            <div className={styles.studentInfoContainer}>
              <div className={styles.studentHeader}>
                <p className={styles.studentName}>{student.firstName} {student.lastName}</p>
              </div>
              <ul className={styles.studentDetail}>
                <li>Email: {student.email}</li>
                <li>Company: {student.company}</li>
                <li>Skill: {student.skill}</li>
                <li>Average: {findAverageGrade(student.grades)}%</li>

                <button onClick={() => {
                  setIsShown(!isShown);
                }}>
                  +
                </button>
                {isShown ? <div>
                  <table className={styles.gradesTable}>
                    <tbody>
                      {student.grades.map((grade) => (
                        <tr key={uuidv4()}>
                          <td>Test</td>
                          <td>{grade}%</td>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                : null }
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        )
      )}
      </div>
    </>
  )
  
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: dose every student has id?

Comment: Your code is not complete. Please make sure to include enough code so it can be run and displays the error. `styles` is not defined.

Comment: @Hesam yes every student has an ID

Comment: @a.h.g. Okay, I added the imports and export of the component

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-galileo-6ol587?file=/src/App.js). You need a new component (Student). In that component you have to declare its own `isShown` state. If you use one in the parent component, it's obviously going to affect all students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the mapping part to another component and import it in map part. In this way you will have still same structure and it will work without any extra logic

*NEW COMPONENT*

```
const Students = ({student}) => {

            const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(true);
            return (
              <div key={student.email} className={styles.studentItem}>
                    <img className={styles.studentImage} src={student.pic} />
                    <div className={styles.studentInfoContainer}>
                      <div className={styles.studentHeader}>
                        <p className={styles.studentName}>{student.firstName} {student.lastName}</p>
                      </div>
                      <ul className={styles.studentDetail}>
                        <li>Email: {student.email}</li>
                        <li>Company: {student.company}</li>
                        <li>Skill: {student.skill}</li>
                        <li>Average: {findAverageGrade(student.grades)}%</li>

                        <button onClick={() => {
                          setIsShown(!isShown);
                        }}>
                          +
                        </button>
                        {isShown ? <div>
                          <table className={styles.gradesTable}>
                            <tbody>
                              {student.grades.map((grade) => (
                                <tr key={uuidv4()}>
                                  <td>Test</td>
                                  <td>{grade}%</td>
                                </tr>
                              ))}
                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                        : null }
                      </ul>
                    </div>
               </div>
          )
}
```

*HOME COMPONENT*

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import styles from "./Home.module.css";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const Home = () => {

  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const [filteredStudents, setFilteredStudents] = useState([]);

  const fetchStudents = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students`);
    setStudents(response.data.students);
    setFilteredStudents(response.data.students);
    console.log(response.data.students);

  }

  const findAverageGrade = arr => {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sum += parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
    return sum / arr.length;
  }

  const searchStudentName = async (searchName) => { 
    const searchNameFiltered = searchName.toLowerCase();
    console.log(searchNameFiltered);
    
    if (searchNameFiltered === "") {
      fetchStudents();
      return;
    }

    var newArray = await students.filter((student) => {
      return student.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchNameFiltered)
      || student.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchNameFiltered);
    })

    await setFilteredStudents(newArray);
  }

  const toggleGrades = () => {
    console.log("toggle");
    
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStudents();

  }, [])
  

  return(
    <>
      <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search by name" onChange={(event) => searchStudentName(event.target.value) }/>
        {filteredStudents.map((student) => (
           <Student student={student} />
        )
      )}
      </div>
    </>
  )
  
}

export default Home;
```

Note: I did not include export import parts of component and css but it's the easy part

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to do it without having to create another component though?

Comment: This is the cleanest way in React, you can do also with checking ids of students but it will make your code looks bad and long @jayweezy

Comment: Ok thanks for letting me know! Can you also include in your answer how to do it in the way you just mentioned as well? I would just like to see the differences and find out why I would use one way over the other